# Add type annotation for property value shorthand

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

`MergedObject` can hold an arbitrary number of `MyClass` instances variable name to `MyClass` instance key value pairs, where the property name is the variable name e.g `Obj1` and the value is the `MyClass` instance. How do I add a type annotation for `MergedObject`?

```
class MyClass {
  a: string;
  constructor(a: string) {
    this.a = a
  }
}

const Obj1 = new MyClass('one')
const Obj2 = new MyClass('two')

const MergedObject = {
  Obj1, Obj2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contents of `MergedObject` change over time, you're using `MergedObject` like a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), so you might consider actually using a `Map` (in this case, a `Map<string, MyClass>`):

```typescript
const MergedObject = new Map<string, MyClass>(
    Object.entries({
        Obj1,
        Obj2,
    })
);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vTALmggBcAnASwDsBzAbix2AHsLiSBXYIxkgCn0NKUqASnT0cOIgAsyEAHRhoAXlx0JAXwyaMTFkWgB5AEYArAIzLoFAKYB3OEhQQeAImbWXwuruKHTAJksbewRkSGcXIltGT29mX1hrEiprABNjE2tOILs4MAAHAB5WIQAaBzCoAD4ecT9MzjlrCkFrZ0wJCQyzUrqugN6NYQwvIA)

If its contents *don't* change over time (it's a static construct), there's no need to apply a type annotation to it, TypeScript will infer the type just fine from the initializer:

```typescript
const MergedObject = {
    Obj1,
    Obj2,
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vTALmggBcAnASwDsBzAbix2AHsLiSBXYIxkgCn0NKUqASnT0cOIgAsyEAHRhoAXlx0JAXwyaMTFkWgB5AEYArAIzLoFAKYB3OEhQQeAImbWXwuruKHTAJksbewRkSGcXIltGT29mX1hrEiprABNjE2tOS0wJDLMAGnE-E38i9TpE5LSMrKIMAHoG6AA9AH4gA)

That also has the advantage that it has strongly-typed keys (`"Obj1" | "Obj2"`, not `string`). But if you wanted to loosen it, you could use `Record<string, MyClass>`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible type annotation would be an object with a string index signature containing `MyClass` values.

```
const MergedObject: Record<string, MyClass> = {
  Obj1, Obj2
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1pgFzQgBcAnASwDsBzAbi2mAHtyjiBXYQh4gCjwJIqUAlOjrZCAC1IQAdGGgBeHHQC%20GNRkbNC0APIAjAFYBGRdHIBTAO5wkKCNwDkTC46GamRPUYBMZyzYIyJAOjoRWDG4YHtpwFsSUFgAmBoYWHPgASulcSQA8LIIANLbBUAB8ZpjYqcYlqT7qQA)